# Word 2010 heading numbering - i want to have all Exhibit numbers as A-1, etc.?

Tags: microsoft-word

I do a lot of Exhibit A-1, A-2 headings and so on but I can only get the "-1" portion to work if I type it in manually after I get the automatic Exhibit A in place.  This also allows me to cross-reference both of them together just fine but is a pain to create and use and most users do not even know what I have done to get this in place.

I can only get this to work if I enter the "-1" manually after the automatic Exhibit A?  Any ideas on how to make this all automatic and on one line or one style, the first Exhibit A style?

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood you correctly, you can achieve this with multilevel list.

Click on "Define a new Multi-Level List". Select the first level, and under "Number style for this level" selected the capitalized list, and under "Formatting" add the "-1" after the letter.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NKjj.png)

Then click the second level, change the "Aligned at" to match the first level, select "1，2,3" as the Number style, change "Start at" to 2, and select teh first option under "Include level number from".

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHJAF.png)

You can then create a list (say, in your Table of Contents) for each heading A-1, B-1, C-1. If you want to create A-2, press enter after A-1 then tab forward.

In the header of your actual Exhibit, add a cross-reference, select "Numbered item" as referenced type, "Paragraph number" under "Insert reference to", then select the exhibit reference you want to insert.